# Is it possible to use std::thread to parallelize on Intel Xeon Phi?

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, stdthread, intel-mic

I know that classic example of parallelization on Intel Xeon Phi are done with `OpenMP`. But is it possible to use `std::thread` to automatically launch tasks on Xeon Phi ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes, please see http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/choosing-the-right-threading-framework

Answer (score 0):

The current shipping compilers that support Xeon Phi do not support C++11 and therfore do not support std::Thread.